# Find wifi password length with cmd

Tags: wireless-networking, cmd.exe

I have recently been trying to learn all the command prompts network capability's. I was just wondering if any body knows a series of commands or a single command that will allow me to find my wi-fi password length.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Passwords are meant to be secure and unknownable, even the length.  If you can find a utility to get the password length your device is insecure.  If that is the case get a new wi-fi device that is actually secure.